# how to Positioning AJAX ModalPopupExtender in the right of the screen in any screen width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

i want to position the ModalPopupExtender  at the right of screen depend the screen width
because when i use x and y to positioning the ModalPopupExtender  sometime it not appear if the screen size is small:
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe3" runat="server"
TargetControlId="Button13" PopupControlID="ModalPanel3"
OkControlID="Button13" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground2"   X="1350" Y="290" />
how i can position the ModalPopupExtender  at the right of the screen regardless the width
i putted the ModalPopupExtender  inside a div and didn't work
i added a javascript code also the same

function setPopup() {

            var pop = $find("mpe");

            var scr = screen.width;

            if (pop != null) {

                

                pop.set_X(scr * 0.7);

                pop.set_Y(scr * 0.5);

               

            }

        }

```
                  <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Height="34px" Width="48px" Style="background-image:url('../Images/png2.ico'); background-position: center; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;"  OnClientClick="setPopup()"/>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

That is the "one" bit issue for the popup extender. It does not support css, or % or "em" for the x and y setting.

You can kluge it somewhat like this:

Only set the y setting - say for near top of screen.

So, I have this:

```
        </style>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Testpop" CssClass="btn"/>

        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
            BehaviorID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender"  
            TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="MyPopDiv"
             CancelControlID="cmdCancel" BackgroundCssClass="myright"    
            y="20"
            >
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

so, y=20 is good near the top.

Now, for right, the x setting "over rides" most css settings.

But, whacking it a bit and some kluge, this :

```
<div id="MyPopDiv" runat="server"
    style="position:static;width:30em;margin-left:30%;right:30px;top:20%!important;padding:3px;border:solid;box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px grey;padding:9px;"
    >
    <h4>Enter Discount Amount</h4>
    %<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="56px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="Override invoice discount"
        runat="server" style="margin-left:20px" />
    <br />
    <div style="float:right">
    <asp:Button ID="cmdOk" runat="server" Text="ok" CssClass="btn" />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"
        style="margin-left:10px" CssClass="btn"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

So, now I get, see this (from a 1920 monitor, I can do to about half, and it looks not too bad).

[image]

The other suggestion, and one I started using due to the above issue?

You consider adopting jQuery.UI dialogs. It's always a crying shame to have to "adopt" a whole new library like jquery.UI for just ONE little feature.

The aj toolkit is really fantastic, but it often does show its age. Of course if you adopt jQuery.UI dialogs, then you having to write some client side JavaScript code to make this work - which again is a huge bonus of the aj toolkit (you don't wind up having in most cases to write ANY client side JavaScript for the aj toolkit features)

Comment: thank you for your help and i found a solution i added ClientIDMode="Static" to the modal popup after that the OnClientClick="setPopup()" in the button work fine now i need the event that in the button the same goes to dropdownlist i've already added onchange="setPopup()" and thats not work i think because it has a postback event please help